# More sidekiq instances vs higher concurrency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I'm setting up my sidekiq on production and I'm wondering how should I setup sidekiq instances.

I've got 3 different types of workers and 8 CPU cores and the question is if it's better to make 3 instances with concurrencies 8, 15 and 12 or should it be 8 instances with lower concurrencies for each instance, or maybe something between like for example 6 instances?

What are the pros and cons of the ways I've mentioned?

Comment: _"with concurrencies 8, 15 and 12"_ – where do these numbers come from?

Comment: Number 35 is the sum of instances concurrencies which were set up in previous version of sidekiq instances on this production server. Do you think that different number of threats will be better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer: depends on your task.

I'm assuming you use MRI Ruby. If there is a lot of IO (disk, network), you can go with fewer instances and higher concurrency.

If you have a lot of CPU intensive tasks you are probably better of using separate instances. That means more unix processes but "true" concurrency.